# Get rid of Comments and Share boxes from Word 2021 Ribbon

Tags: microsoft-word

I just installed Microsoft Home and Student 2021 to upgrade Word and found new little drop-down menu boxes for “Comments” and “Share” in the Ribbon. I’m guessing it’s a long shot, but I only work offline and is there any way to get rid of them as they are features I will never use?

For that matter I have never used “Sign in” either and it is all clutter.

[image]

Comment: Same icons in Office 365 and you need to be an Office Account admin to remove these.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GPO, but only make it gray (not clickable).
Download the [GPO template](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49030), open GPO Editor > User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Microsoft Word 2016 > Disable Items in User Interface > Customize > Disable Commands > Enable > Type 26594 in Enter Command Bar ID to disable.
[image]

Comment: It might be helpful if you explain the significance of the value of 26594. For instance how do you know that is the correct value?

Comment: Microsoft has made it possible to disable nearly every feature by assigning nearly every button and short cut a number.  You can get a list of those numbers from what Microsoft has cleverly named: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=50745

Comment: You should modify your answer to include this vital information